# No usable version of libssl was found Aborted (core dumped) (Powershell on ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: powershell, ubuntu

I have installed powershell on ubuntu 21.04:

```
$ sudo snap install powershell --classic
snap "powershell" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

But when I try to run it I get:

```
$ powershell
PowerShell 7.1.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

No usable version of libssl was found
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libssl1.0-dev' for regex 'libssl1.0'
Note, selecting 'libssl1.0.0' for regex 'libssl1.0'
Note, selecting 'libssl1.0.2' for regex 'libssl1.0'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Still same error. This worked before with ubuntu 20.10.

Also related - but not solved:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465105

Any suggestions?